# Select multiple values in XML file and concatenation them with xQuery

Tags: sql, xml, select, concatenation, xquery

I have the following XML:

```
<items>
 <item value="1"/>
 <item value="2"/>
 <item value="4"/>
</items>
```

and I would like to select all item value and concatenate them like this - see below - with XQuery :

```
1.2.4
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question:

1. getting values out of xml
2. concatenating multiple values together

The second part of your question has been covered off very nicely in the answers to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/1208914)

In terms of getting the values out of your xml, try the below:

```
-- Your xml variable

DECLARE @xml AS XML = '<items>
                         <item value="1"/>
                         <item value="2"/>
                         <item value="4"/>
                       </items>'


-- Example of selecting the values into rows

SELECT 
  item.value('.', 'int') 
FROM 
   @xml.nodes('/items/item/@value') as T1(item) 

-- Use your favourite/'best for your circumstance' method of 
-- concatenating the rows into one string 
-- see https://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/1208914 for other ways

SELECT 
  item.value('.', 'varchar(50)') + ' ' as 'data()' 
FROM 
  @xml.nodes('/items/item/@value') as T1(item) 
for xml path('')
```

I've put the code above into a sql fiddle that you can access and play with here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18144/0

Answer (score 1):

Using XQuery you can simply select the values using XPath and join them together using a dot.

```
string-join(/items/item/@value, '.')
```